# Shutting down ExecutorService that is processing a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, executorservice, shutdown

I'm working on a program that processing a large stream of items and sends each result to a REST server. That server has a rate limit of 2000 requests per hour, so the program must pause a while between processing two items. Items failed to process should be presented to the user afterwards.

It all worked fine, until I discovered that `shutdownNow()` isn't working when the program is closed. The UI closes but the executor keeps working. Underneath a brief summary of the code.

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
SomeProcessor p = new SomeProcessor();

void process() {
    exec.submit(() -> {
        Stream<SomeObject> s = ...
        List<SomeObject> failed = p.process(s);
        // show failed in UI
    };
}

void exit() {
    exec.shutdownNow();
}
```

And the `SomeProcessor` class:

```
List<SomeObject> process(Stream<SomeObject> s) {
    List<SomeObject> failed = s
        .sequential()
        .filter(o -> !ignore(o)) // ignore irrelevant items
        .peek(o -> pause()) // make sure not to exceed server's rate limit
        .filter(o -> !process(o)) // keep items failed to process
        .collect(Collectors.asList());
    return failed;
}

void pause() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.interrupted();
    }
}

boolean process(SomeObject o) {
    if (Thread.interrupted()) // make task interruptible
        // *** but then what? ***
    try {
        // process o and send result to server
        return true;
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I guess that `shutdownNow()` wasn't working because the task isn't interruptible. So I'm trying to make the task interruptible, but I don't know what it should look like. Any ideas?

And a bonus question too. The `pause()` method does what it should do. Still I'd rather use something like `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(.)`, but then processing a stream of tasks. Does anything exist like that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to read what `shutDownNow` does, it interrupts all running tasks, if those tasks know how to respond to those interrupts is a different story

Comment: Yes and so my question is how to make a task respond to the interrupt within this specific context... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `pause` method:

```
void pause() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.interrupted();
    }
}
```

You are already detecting interruption at this point but react on it by setting the interrupt state of the thread again, or at least trying to do so, as `Thread.interrupted()` should be `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to achieve this, which would be fine, if you do not want to support interruption, but here it is counter-productive. It will cause your next `sleep` call to throw an `InterruptedException` immediately, which you handle the same way, and so on. As a result, you’re not only proceeding with the processing of the remaining elements, you’re doing it without the sleeping between the elements.

When you change the method to

```
void pause() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("interrupted");
    }
}
```

interruption will terminate your stream operation with the `IllegalStateException`. For clarity, you may define your own exception type (extending `RuntimeException`) for this scenario, distinguishable from all other exception types.